# How to handle session invalidation for username / password OAuth flow?

Tags: oauth2, authentication, heroku, node-salesforce

## Question

What's the proper way to monitor for session timeout and automatically get a new session using [node-salesforce](https://github.com/stomita/node-salesforce)?

## Background

Building a basic node.js app on heroku.  Using the OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credential flow to login.  Eventually the session expires and being a node.js noob, I'm not exactly sure how I should be setting this up to check the session and update it if it's invalid.  Doing I just fail the method call and instead get a new token and hope the end result isn't totally weird to the end user or result in data integrity issues?  Should I be using a totally different OAuth flow? (
All the Salesforce oauth docs says to avoid the username pass flow, but I don't understand what else you would use for an autonomous server).  Should I just ditch OAuth completely and do a login on EVERY call?

## Code

### Initialize Salesforce Connection

```
var sf = require('node-salesforce');

var salesforce_username = process.env.SALESFORCE_USERNAME,
    salesforce_password = process.env.SALESFORCE_PASSWORD;

var oauth_options = {
  loginUrl : process.env.SALESFORCE_LOGIN_URL,
  clientId : process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_KEY,
  clientSecret : process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  redirectUri : process.env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URL
};

var salesforceConnection = new sf.Connection({oauth2 : oauth_options});
salesforceConnection.login(salesforce_username, salesforce_password, function(err, userInfo) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  console.log(salesforceConnection.accessToken);
  console.log(salesforceConnection.instanceUrl);
});
```

### Query

```
function getClientSites(callback) { 
  salesforceConnection.sobject('Account').select('*')execute(function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.error(err);  // <-- failing here when the session expires
    callback(results);
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic session refresh within [node-salesforce](https://github.com/stomita/node-salesforce) when you use the password flow.  In [connection.js:215](https://github.com/stomita/node-salesforce/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L215) it will refresh the session if the session has expired but only if you using the access_token and refresh_token instead, not password.

If you have to use password, you could catch the error returned by the 401 status code in connection.js:247 and use the login or initialization function to refresh the session.